# the blue screen in android studio disappeared

Tags: android-studio

please help
im new to android studio and from the two screens for layout the blue one on the left disappeared
my API version is 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing what you're looking for is the `Blueprint` Design Surface. Your currently viewing the `Basic` Design Surface.

You can toggle between `Basic`, `Blueprint` and both by either pressing the **B** key, or by clicking on the **Select Design Surface** button - it looks like a blue diamond stacked on-top of another blue diamond . (I've circled it in the image you provided)

[image: Select Design Surface Button]